# Unable to launch Visual Studio 2008 dll on Modern Windows

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I have a dll that build by visual studio 2008 and I want to use it in my application build by visual studio 2019. But when I link the DLL to my application I failed to start the app due to the old dll requires files msvcp80.dll and msvcr80.dll. I have a lot of Visual Studio runtimes on my Windows but anyway this dll failed to load. 
Probably the issue is that this old dll has a external manifest file that not suitable/corresponds to the my modern Windows Server. 
Is any way to make this old dll works? 
PS: I don't have source code of this dll.
The manifest is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
  <assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
    <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50727.4053' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to run executables (including DLLs) built with the C/C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2008 (on a machine that doesn't have VS-2008 installed), you need to install the VC-2008 Redistributable package.

This is free, can be distributed without licence with your application(s), and installs the required run-time libraries that your PC is missing.

The installer program can be downloaded and/or installed from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29).

EDIT: Following the comment posted by Hans Passant, it appears that what you *actually* need is the [VC-2005 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26347) in order to install the `msvcr80.dll` and similar RT libraries (the version numbers can be confusing).

Comment: The OP gave you bad info, he needs the redist for VS2005.  VS2002 == VC70, VS2003 == VC71, VS2005 == VC80, VC2008 == VC90.

Comment: Thanks for that critical piece of information, @Hans! I have added a 'suitable note' to my answer.

Comment: Hello, I was wrong, the dll was build by visual studio 2005. not 2008. 
I've installed the vcredist_x86.EXE but it doesn't help, MSVCP80.DLL and MSVCR80.DLL are still required. 

Is it possible that my dll was build by VS 2005 SP2, SP3, etc?

Comment: In the C:\Windows\WinSxS I have the following:
 - amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.8428_none_88dcdb0b2fb19957
- x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a
- x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.8428_none_d08a11e2442dc25d

Comment: @sluge Maybe you have a different platform? x64 (or even IA64)? If so, you need to install the redistributable for *that* platform - vcredist_x64.exe, for example. Or check for the DLL files in C:\Windows\System - if they're not there, look for them elsewhere on your PC and copy them there.

Comment: No, All my binaries are x86
Is it critical that I don't have the exact crt version: 8.0.50727.4053?